ERROR S3 AWS "No such key": The specified key does not exist
Im testing lambda function that is triggered when an object is created in a prefix directory
like so : s3-Bucket/{prefix}/{parent-folder}/{sub-folders}/video-File.mp4. I'm currently able to log the event payload from json test im using with a file path that exist in the s3-Bucket but when we try and getObject for download i encountered the error no such key or "ERROR    AWS Error Message: The specified key does not exist".
I've checked my roles and permissions and all looks ok as in my s3 bucket is configured to allow read, write, list, delete, IAM policy.I'm not sure what else i should try or what causes this error?
This is my lambda handler:
    export const handler: S3Handler = async (event: S3Event): Promise<void> => {
  console.log("Handler started", JSON.stringify(event));
  try {
    for (const record of event.Records) {
      const bucket = record.s3.bucket.name;
      const objectKey = decodeURIComponent(
        record.s3.object.key.replace(/\+/g, " ")
      );
      console.log(`Processing file: ${objectKey}`);
      console.log(`Bucket: ${bucket}`);

      const s3Url = `https://s3.amazonaws.com/${bucket}/${objectKey}`;
      console.log(`Access S3 URL: ${s3Url}`);

      const subFolder = objectKey.split("/").slice(-2, -1)[0];
      console.log(`File is in subfolder: ${subFolder}`);

      if (
        allowedSubFolders.includes(subFolder) &&
        fileExtensions.some((ext) => objectKey.endsWith(ext))
      ) {
        await processFile(bucket, objectKey);
      } else {
        console.log(
          `Skipping file ${objectKey} as it does not meet the criteria.`
        );
      }
    }
  } catch (error: any) {
    console.error("Error in handler", { error });
  } finally {
    console.log("Handler completed");
  }
}; 

Lambda role document :
    {
  "partial": false,
  "policies": [
    {
      "arn": "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_ID:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole",
      "document": {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
          {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
              "logs:CreateLogGroup",
              "logs:CreateLogStream",
              "logs:PutLogEvents",
              "s3:GetObject",
              "s3:PutObject",
              "s3:DeleteObject",
              "s3:ListBucket",
              "lambda:InvokeFunction"
            ],
            "Resource": [
              "arn:aws:logs:us-east-1:ACCOUNT_ID:*",
              "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME/*",
              "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME",
              "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:ACCOUNT_ID:function:FUNCTION_NAME"
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      "id": "POLICY_ID",
      "name": "AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole",
      "type": "managed"
    }
  ],
  "resources": {
    "logs": {
      "service": {
        "icon": "logs_icon_data",
        "name": "Amazon CloudWatch Logs"
      }
    },
    "s3": {
      "service": {
        "icon": "s3_icon_data",
        "name": "Amazon S3"
      }
    },
    "lambda": {
      "service": {
        "icon": "lambda_icon_data",
        "name": "AWS Lambda"
      }
    }
  },
  "roleName": "s3AccessRole",
  "trustedEntities": [
    "lambda.amazonaws.com"
  ]
}

s3 policy:
    {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXXX:role/service-role/s3AccessRole"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::example-bucket/video-folder/*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::example-bucket",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "s3:prefix": "video-folder/*"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetBucketLocation",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::example-bucket"
        }
    ]
}


What does processFile do? Can you share a minimal repro of the code?

its a async function that awaits references the download of a file to temp dir, generates a thumbnail, and uploads thumbnail. These main scripts are its own files we import into the index.ts.
`

Well, it's presumably the code that is making the GetObject request that is failing. If you've double-checked that the bucket and key you are passing to it are valid (and you can actually get that object, e.g. using the awscli) then the problem is likely in the code of processFile.

"An error occurred (NoSuchKey) when calling the GetObject operation: The specified key does not exist." This is the error i received in my aws cli. Not sure why, my bucket policy and IAM roles allow for read, write, and list access.

That error cannot be caused by policies or permissions. The object that you are requesting simply does not exist. Double check the bucket and the key, then check to see if the object actually exists e.g. using the S3 console. Make sure you haven't done something silly like included a forward slash at the start of the key e.g. /dogs/snoopy.png which is invalid and should be dogs/snoopy.png.

the object does exist inside AWS thats the puzzling thing.

If the AWS CLI says the object doesn't exist, then that is the fact. Are you able to list the contents of the S3 bucket and show that the object exists?
